# Boostrap columns colliding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Whenever I resize my website to a mobile view of 320 x 480, two of my columns filled with text collide into each other and mash up the text. I tried doing it without columns using just "container-clearfix" but it didn't solve my problem.

The first image shows how the website  text looks on 320 x 480 for small mobiles [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wkfyy.jpg)

Here is the JS Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/14124/

```css
#big-image {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.col-md-12 {
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}
#text-four {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 450px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  left: 20%;
}
#text-four-p {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: auto;
  bottom: 830%;
  left: 15%;
  text-align: center;
}
.US {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: auto;
  bottom: 250%;
  left: 15%;
  text-align: center;
}
.EU {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: auto;
  bottom: 250%;
  right: 15%;
  text-align: center;
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  #text-four,
  #text-four-p {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">

  <img src="image/4.jpg" class="img-responsive" id="big-image">


  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3 id="text-four"> HOW TO WATCH SHORTSHD (US) OR SHORTSTV (EUROPE)</h3>
      <p id="text-four-p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sit amet bibendum lorem. Nullam molestie lectus eros, vel ornare mi</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <div class="US">
            <h2> ShortsHD (US)</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur at lobortis diam. Nam quis mauris ipsum. Fusce ac felis pharetra, egestas ante ut, malesuada quam. Vestibulum id arcu eget ipsum semper vestibulum. Nullam vitae ipsum tellus.
              Aenean nec sem consequat, mattis dolor eu, eleifend lectus. Nam id purus hendrerit, lacinia massa a, ullamcorper massa. Cras eget risus ut nulla cursus vestibulum. Duis id tellus fringilla, ultricies est id, sagittis velit. Morbi quis ante
              pharetra, tincidunt neque non, ultricies diam. Cras ornare risus vel nisl gravida, non viverra lacus efficitur. Nam consectetur dolor eros, quis iaculis arcu accumsan at. Aenean vitae lectus eros.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-pull-6">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <div class="EU">
            <h2> ShortsTV (EU)</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur at lobortis diam. Nam quis mauris ipsum. Fusce ac felis pharetra, egestas ante ut, malesuada quam. Vestibulum id arcu eget ipsum semper vestibulum. Nullam vitae ipsum tellus.
              Aenean nec sem consequat, mattis dolor eu, eleifend lectus. Nam id purus hendrerit, lacinia massa a, ullamcorper massa. Cras eget risus ut nulla cursus vestibulum. Duis id tellus fringilla, ultricies est id, sagittis velit. Morbi quis ante
              pharetra, tincidunt neque non, ultricies diam. Cras ornare risus vel nisl gravida, non viverra lacus efficitur. Nam consectetur dolor eros, quis iaculis arcu accumsan at. Aenean vitae lectus eros.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change position on media query

```
@media only screen 
     and (min-device-width : 320px) 
     and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    .US{
      position: relative;
      overflow:auto;
      bottom: 250%;
      left: 15%;
      text-align: center;
     }
     .EU{
     position: relative;
     overflow:auto;
     bottom: 250%;
     right: 15%;
     text-align: center;
     }
     }
```

Comment: Thanks but they are still colliding.

Comment: remove bottom property

Comment: Still not working properly even if  I remove the bottom property of the media query...

Comment: While in mobile the text still comes out like I have shown in IMAGE 2

Comment: Here is the js fiddle link, strech the image in order to see it how it looks on a bigger view : http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/14124/

Answer (score 0):

You have used `position:absolute` in many elements inside main container

That collide with each other and getting same position

Make one parent container and give `position:absolute` and set child container  according to your requirement